# Update manager integration

Tags: software-center, update-manager

Will the update manager and the Software Center be merged into one in a future release? I think that would be an ideal thing to do, and I believe PackageKit does that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is ontopic here, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The two tools serve fairly different purposes, so it isn't clear that having a single UI covering both use cases would be a win.

Updating your system should be a very simple and straight forward operation, or you risk users not doing it and leaving their system at risk.  So I don't think complicating the Update Manager UI would be an improvement.

Now on the backend side it certainly makes sense to share code, since the backend tasks of the two tools are related.  And in fact they do share code through the `aptdaemon` backend.

Comment: Not really. Synaptic has the ability to install software and update your system.

Comment: I'm not saying it is impossible to do both tasks from the same UI, but it is a lot less obvious how to update your system through Synaptic when compared to Update Manager.  My point wasn't whether it was technically feasible to handle both tasks in one UI, but whether it was a good idea.